# `loss` passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled. --> optimizer.minimize()

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I am trying to resolve a Linear Regression problem using TensorFlow & I came across this RuntimeError
"`loss` passed to Optimizer.compute_gradients should be a function when eager execution is enabled."
after execution of '**train = optimizer.minimize(loss)**' in the below code :

a = tf.Variable(20.0)

b = tf.Variable(30.2)

y = a * train_x + b

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - train_y))

optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.05)

train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

where **train_x, train_y** --> a set of array values from a column of data frame

Answer (score 0):

When eager execution is enabled, `loss` should be a Python function that takes no arguments and computes the value to be minimized.

Comment: So does that mean I should disable eager execution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
def y():
   return a * train_x + b
```

as `y`.

Or disable eager execution using:

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```